# How to plot phasors of signals?

Tags: matlab, math, plot

I have 3 singals and I'm trying to plot their [phasors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) and their sum. I need to plot them end to end to demonstrate phasor addition. That is, the first phasor must start from the origin. The second phasor must start from the end of the first phasor. The third phasor must start from the end of the second one. In this way, the end point of the third phasor is the resulting phasor (considering that it starts at the origin). Horizontal and vertical axes are the real and imaginary axes, respectively in range of [-30, 30].

I just started using matlab today and this is due the night. I tried using plot, plot2, plot3, compass, and several ways but with all of them i failed. Compass was the closest to success.

I have amplitude and phase values of each phasor.

So how can I accomplish this task? Can you help me to draw two of phasors?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Related Example: from http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e84/lectures/ch3/node2.html

[image: a]

**[example by spektre]**

- [image: phasors image example]

Comment: Should every phasor be represented by an arrow, or just the last one (like in the picture). Do you need arrows at all? (If not, it's a lot simpler)

Comment: Interesting how this question has 3 upvotes, 2 favourites.... but no answers.  Why? Because we are asking for clarification, and no response from the OP.  You want to [step up to the plate](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=stepping+up+to+the+plate) OP?

Comment: @deve arrow should be in all phasors, but the image in OP is not the right one for this task. in this case the arrows just visualize the rotation but the vector arrow should be at the  thick line pointing outwards the center. on this image there is no summation of  vectors there are just 2 vectors. OP needs just something like common vector addition image which can be rotated around point (0,0) by some angle (if he wants to see the state at some specific time)

Comment: @Deve I don't need arrows.

Comment: @user4220128 then just any line drawing capable API will suffice , first line is `[(0,0),(Ax,Ay)]` second is [(Ax,Ay),(Ax+Bx,Ay+By)] third is [(Ax+Bx,Ay+By),(Ax+Bx+Cx,Ay+By+Cy)] and so on ... I do not use matlab  so I cant help more ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example should get you started:

First, the three phasors are defined.

```
% Define three complex numbers by magnitude and phase
ph1 = 20*exp(1i*0.25*pi);
ph2 = 10*exp(1i*0.7*pi);
ph3 = 5*exp(1i*1.2*pi);
```

Then, using `cumsum`, a vector containing `ph1, ph1+ph2, ph1+ph2+ph3` is calculated.

```
% Step-wise vector sum
vecs = cumsum([ph1; ph2; ph3]);
vecs = [0; vecs]; % add origin as starting point
```

The complex numbers are plotted by real and imaginary part.

```
% Plot
figure;
plot(real(vecs), imag(vecs), '-+');
xlim([-30 30]);
ylim([-30 30]);
xlabel('real part');
ylabel('imaginary part');
grid on;
```

This produces the following figure:
[image: plot produced by the above code]

Answer (score 2):

```
figure(1); hold on;
ang = [0.1 0.2 0.7] ; % Angles in rad
r = [1 2 4] ; % Vector of radius
start = [0 0]
for i=1:numel(r)
plot([start(1) start(1)+r(i)*cos(ang(i))],[start(2) start(2)+r(i)*sin(ang(i))],'b-+')
start=start+[r(i)*cos(ang(i)) r(i)*sin(ang(i))]
end
plot([0 start(1)],[0 start(2)],'r-')
```